# Running app with capacitor IOS is loading at 'capacitor:app' instead localhost, getting cors error

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic4, capacitor

I'm running an Ionic app with capacitor on an iphone 7 plus.
I'm using xcode and everything is ok
when I run the app, with the phone connected, everything works, but the app start running in
"capacitor://app" instead of localhost.

I have configure a port in *capacitor.config.json*, and it was working until today,
now, when I run the applicatoin, the xcode console said

> loading at localhost:MICONFIGUREPORT

and worked perfectly.

Now, is running at 'capacitor://app' although is working right
I have problems with the CORS
even I allow the origin "capacitor://app" in my serve but still having the CORS origin problem.

I'm using Ionic 4 and

```
"@capacitor/android": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
"@capacitor/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
"@capacitor/core": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
"@capacitor/ios": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
```